# For a locally compact group $G$, does the embedding $L^1(G) \subset C^*_r(G) \subset L^2(G)$ hold in general?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Something I'm a little confused on I think-- rusty on my measure theory! So I'm pretty sure I convinced myself that in general for $f \in C_c(G)$, $||f||_2 \leq ||f||_{op} \leq ||f||_1$.

However, does this imply the above nesting? I know that $L^1$ is contained in both, so it's mainly the embedding $C^*_r(G) \subset L^2(G)$ which I could do with a little explanation for!

The reason I thought this might be the case was from reading the paper "Rapidly Decreasing Functions in Reduced C^* algebras of Groups" by Jolissaint:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247333231_Rapidly_Decreasing_Functions_in_Reduced_C_-Algebras_of_Groups

On the top of page 6 he gives a brief explanation, which I do not understand!

Comment: The inclusion $L^1(G)\subset L^2(G)$ does not hold in general, take $G=\mathbb{R}$ for example.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, that was bothering me.  I'm still working on trying to understand the difference between the discrete and locally compact cases ;)

Answer (score 0):

in a slightly unorthodox fashion wanted to answer my own question! Okay so basically consider the map:
$$\iota:C^*_r(G) \rightarrow L^2(G) \quad a \mapsto a(\delta_1)$$
Where $a$ acts via the left regular representation. This map is clearly continuous. Considering both the left regular representation $\lambda$ and the right regular representation $\rho$ it is known that these representations commute, i.e. for all $x, y \in C^*_r(G), \; \lambda_x \rho_y=\rho_y \lambda_x$. Then, $\iota(a)=\iota(b)$ implies that $\rho_x(\iota(a))=\rho_x(\iota_b)$. In other words, $\rho_x \lambda_a \delta_1=\rho_x \lambda_b \delta_1$ using the fact the representations commute this simplifies to $\lambda_a \delta_x=\lambda_b \delta_x$. Therefore, $a=b$.

As pointed out this shows the inclusion $C^*_r(G) \subset L^2(G)$, and the other inclusion is false.

Comment: $\delta_1$ is not an element of $L^2(G)$ unless $G$ is discrete.

Comment: Is it not? This because it would be identified with the zero function?

Comment: If you mean by $\delta_1$ the function that is $1$ at $0$ and $0$ elsewhere, then yes. Of course this makes your map $\iota$ highly non-injective. But typically $\delta_1$ denotes the distribution that maps $f$ to $f(1)$. This is a regular distribution (with respect to the Haar measure) if and only if $G$ is discrete.

Comment: So what about the locally compact case? Is $C^*_r(G) \subset L^2(G)$